# how to get error function and parameter for each divideInd in Neural Network using Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have this code:

```
load bending_data
net = newff(I, O, [i j],{'tansig' 'tansig' 'purelin'},'trainscg');  %'divideind'
net.divideFcn = 'divideInd';
%now I split data
trainInd=1:50;
valInd=51:65;
testInd=66:81;
[trainP,valP,testp]=divideind(I,trainInd,valInd,testInd);
[traint,valt,testt]=divideind(O,trainInd,valInd,testInd);
y=sim(net, I);
```

How to get the error only for say training data set? and how i will specify the input training set for finding error? please help...

Comment: On StackOverflow, prefix lines of code with four spaces.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/nnet/ref/adapt.html :

```
[net,Y,E,Pf,Af,tr] = adapt(net,P,T,Pi,Ai) takes
```

...

```
E   Network errors
```